# ¿Como poner hash a una url de asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

en realidad no se como explicar este tema, lo que pasa
es que hecho mi aplicacion en mvc y asp .net, entonces cada vez que entro a mi menu de mi web y acceso a una pagina mi url es esta:
localhost:1523/es/quienessomos

Menu que utilizo en asp.net

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a  href="@Url.Action("quienessomos", "es")">Quiénes Somos</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

y aparece mi pagina de quienes somos , hasta ahi esta bien porque renderiza a las vistas.

Pero estoy añadiendo un tema que me dio el frontend, el tema fue hecho en html, y se necesita que la url sea de esta forma para que renderiza bien a la pagina y funcione su tema, parece que busca un .hash:
localhost:8090/es/#quienessomos

el menu que usa en html:

```
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#quienes-somos">Quiénes Somos</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Bueno mi problema es que la animacion que hace este script que adjunte no funciona por este problema del hash, porfavor necesito alguna idea gracias.

el usa este script:

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    // $('.ToolTip').tooltip();
    // $('.popOver').popover();

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    
    // new WOW().init();



  //CARRUSEL
  // $('.carousel').carousel({
  //   interval: 2000
  // });

  $('#carousel-home').carousel({
    pause: "false"
  });
});



// $("#bg-anima").animate({width: '100%'}, 800);
// $("#bg-anima").animate({left: '100%'}, 600);



// AJAX
var default_content="";
var urlWeb = window.location.hash;

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!urlWeb){
        // $("#pageContent").load('pages/home.html');
    }else{
        checkURL();
        //filling in the default content
        // default_content = $('#pageContent').html();     //llena la variable default_content con el contenido actual del div #pageContent
        setInterval("checkURL()",50);
    }
});

// var activo="";

$('#navbar-collapse-sup .dropdown-menu li a').click(function (e){
    checkURL(this.hash);

    $("ul li").removeAttr('class');
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");

    $(".navbar-collapse").animate({height: '1'},300,
        function(){
            $(".navbar-collapse").removeClass("in");
        }
    );
    // $("#bg-anima").animate({left: '100%'}, 600);
});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash){
    if(!hash)
        hash = window.location.hash;    //llena la variable hash con el hash de la url actual
    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;
        // FIX - if we've used the history buttons to return to the homepage,
        // fill the pageContent with the default_content
        if(hash=="")
            $('#pageContent').html(default_content);
        else
            $(".navbar").animate({left: '0'},600);
            $("#contenedor-pagina").animate({left: '300px'},600);
            $("#bg-anima").animate({width: '100%'}, 600,
                function(){
                    loadPage(hash);
                }
            );
    }
}

function loadPage(url){
    url = url.replace('#','');
    // $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        // url: "load_page.php",
        url: "pages/" + url + ".html",
        // data: 'page=' + url,
        dataType: "html",
        error: function(){
            $('#pageContent').html( "<p>Page Not Found!!</p>" );
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#pageContent').html( '<img class="loading" src="img/web/loading.gif" alt="loading">' );
        },
        complete: function(){
            // jContent.html( "<p>AJAX - complete()</p>" );
        },
        success: function( msg ){
            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#bg-anima').animate({left: '100%'}, 400);
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                // $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
                $('#bg-anima').animate({width: '0%'}, 0);
                $('#bg-anima').animate({left: '0%'}, 0);

                // $('#menu-extra').addClass('hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg');
                $('#menu-extra').css('display','none');
                $('#menu-extra-nav').addClass('visible-sm visible-md visible-lg');
                $('#redes').addClass('visible-sm visible-md visible-lg');

                $('#carousel-nav').css('display','none');

                $("footer").load('pages/footer.html');
            }
            // $(".container").perfectScrollbar();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que el link es capturado por el evento click de jquery hasta llegar a `loadPage()`

El tema es que alli quitas el # pero estar armando de forma incorrecta la url

Primero no se porque le pones `pages` y despues para que el `.html` se trata de un action de mvc solo debes definir el controller y el action que vas a invocar.

entonces en el link podrias usar

```
<a href="#es/quienes-somos">Quiénes Somos</a>
```

y en la invocacion ajax defines directo url

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "html",
```

sino funciona quizas debas unirle el root del sitio o sea `http://localhost:1523` + url